# UIScrollView + pin items to top before scrolling off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7

I'm replicating a Passbook/iOS7 Reminders interface where there are a bunch of cards stacked on top of each other, offset so the top of the card shows through. There's one main scrollView, with each card added as a subView.

[image]

When the user scrolls up, I want the top most card to pin to the top, so 1 stacks on 0, 2 stack on 1, etc.

I have it working using my scrollview's delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) return;

    int offsetBetweenItems = 50;

    int indexForTopCard = (int)(scrollView.contentOffset.y / offsetBetweenItems);
    Card *card = self.cards[indexForTopCard];

    card.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, card.frame.size.width, card.frame.size.height);
}
```

This is actually working great as long as scroll smoothly and slowly. However,when scrolling aggressively back to the top (0) card, the stacking gets all messed up and I lose my uniform 50px offset.

I think this is happening because of how I'm finding a Card with `indexForTopOfCard`. If I scroll too fast, there's no guarantee I'll be able to adjust each card in order, and sometimes several cards get skipped altogether.

What's the best way to ensure that each card is guaranteed to be adjusted in order?

Comment: Did you try building a collection view custom layout?

Comment: no, i'm not too familiar with how to do that yet.

Comment: You can subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and adjust the frame of each attribute item in layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this easily using a UITableView with sections.

Comment: This seems like comment more..instead of answer!